# Python, selenium and catching specific text in div outside any span or something

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I came across a page i want to scrap a bit - and i cried a lot looking at the structure of address details section. But let's be specific:

I have a result structure like this:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="INFO">
      Foo Bar School of Baz and Qux
      <br>
      <span class="TYPE">
        Wibble school of Wobble
      </span>
      <br>
      <br>
      12th Hurr Durr Street, 12345 Derp
      <br>
      <span>Phone: 123 567 890 </span> <br>
      <span>Fax: 666 69 69 69 </span>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and i want to extract the name and adress of the place using selenium in python. So i wrote xpath which happen to work:

```
(//div[@class='INFO'])[1]//text()[not(parent::span) and normalize-space()]
```

But since things i want to extract aren't elements, just text, they are specified with text() with "don't be inside span" and "don't be whitespace".

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(thing_i_wrote_above)
```

throws

```
mon.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector <the same xpath> is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

I don't see any way to select the element, because closest one is INFO, which happens to contain all of the informations. How to grab these things?

Comment: What output you get when tries this code string `driver.find_element_by_class_name('INFO').text` ?

Comment: @andersson I get: `Foo Bar School of Baz and Qux <newline> Wibble school of Wobble <newline><newline>12th Hurr Durr Street, 12345 Derp <newline> Phone: 123 567 890 <newline> Fax: 666 69 69 69`

Whole address - i wanted to separate that data as much as possible, so it doesn't satisfy me

Comment: @WiktorPrzybylski at this point it may be easier to use regex or python string functions to strip what you want from the returned string. I've experienced similar tear inducing page structures, so I can feel your pain.

Comment: yeah I second @cssko, its better to use regex and strip the string.

Comment: For example, if `foo` is your string, then: `string.split(foo, '\n')` will give you a list of strings demarcated by '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the children text nodes with a piece of JavaScript:

```
# get the container
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".INFO")

# return an array with the text from the children text nodes
texts = driver.execute_script("""
  return Array.from(arguments[0].childNodes)
    .filter(function(o){return o.nodeType === 3 && o.nodeValue.trim().length;})
    .map(function(o){return o.nodeValue.trim();})
  """, element)

print texts
```

You could also use BeautifulSoup to parse the html from the container:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get the container
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".INFO")

# parse the HTML from the container
bs = BeautifulSoup(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))

# list all the children text nodes
texts = [v.strip() for v in bs.html.body.div.findAll(text=True, recursive=False) if v.strip()]

print texts
```